# Shell function, do action with one arg

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to do something simple, such as mkdir based on a given argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

make_picNum() {
    arg1 = $1
    echo "Making picture folder $arg1..."
    echo "mkdir picNum_$arg1"
    echo "Created album folder"
}
```

I'm assuming I have some basic syntax flaws.
The current output/action of running this with any given number as an argument is nada.

Comment: You appear to have declared a function, but not actually called it.

Comment: I'm creating this in a .sh, then chmod +x file.sh and ./file.sh args

Comment: `arg1 = $1` is illegal, it should be written as `arg1="$1"`, note the lack of whitespace between the variable name and the equals sign. You should also always quote variable expansions. If all you are doing is defining functions in this file you should not execute it, instead you should source it: `source file.sh`; after this you can reference the make_picNum function.

Answer (score 2):

Your script defines a function called `make_picNum` but it never calls that function.
Try adding this at the end:

```
make_picNum "$1"
```

Also, you need to remove the spaces around `=`.

Comment: Done, done, and also added keyword function before make_picNum().
And my other clear mistake was echo'ing the command I want, ha.

Comment: Don't use the `function` keyword. It's an unnecessary and nonstandard bashism.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating this in a .sh, then chmod +x file.sh and ./file.sh args

If that's the case, you don't really need that function inside the script, i.e. you can just have this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Making picture folder $1..."
mkdir "picNum_$1"
echo "Created album folder"
```